# Why is the type of null + null implicitly String in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, nullable

The following Kotlin code:

```
val x = null + null
```

results in `x` being of type `String`, which is correct as according to the docs for [`String.plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html):

> Concatenates this string with the string representation of the given [other] object. If either the receiver or the [other] object are null, they are represented as the string "null".

However, I don't understand why this happens - is it due to some special feature of the language?

Comment: Is there a question here?  The blockquote explains why x is a string.

Comment: @MartinJoiner for me it remains strange that the first parameter `null` is the string.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the quote

Comment: @CodyG. you can in the Android Studio to write `null.plus(null)`, and then when you switch to the method you will be able to read the annotation.

Comment: The reference comes from the `plus()` operator. Here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Probably because `String?.plus(Any?)` is the only `plus` function which accepts a nullable type as a receiver in Kotlin library. Therefore, when you call `null + null`, the compiler will treat the first `null` as `String?`.

If you define an extension function where the receiver type is `Int?` and the return type is `Int`, then `x` will be inferred as `Int`.

```
public operator fun Int?.plus(other: Any?): Int = 1
val x = null + null
```

If you declare another similar function within the same file (nullable type as the receiver type), when you call `null + null`, it causes the compile time error: `Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.`.

```
public operator fun Int?.plus(other: Any?): Int = 1
public operator fun Float?.plus(other: Any?): Float = 1F
val x = null + null    //compile time error
```

Answer (score 6):

We need to start with the type of `Nothing`. This type has exactly zero possible values. It's a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), and is a subtype of every other type (not to be confused with `Any`, which is a [supertype of every other type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type)). `Nothing` can be coerced to any type, so that you can do stuff like:

```
fun doStuff(a: Int): String =
    TODO("this typechecks")
```

Moving on to the type of `Nothing?`, meaning `Nothing` or `null`. It has 0 + 1 possible values. So `null` has a type of `Nothing?`. `Nothing?` can be coerced to any nullable type, so that you can do stuff like:

```
var name: String? = null
```

Here `null : Nothing?` is coerced to `String?`.

For some reason, unfortunately, there's [this function defined in stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html):

```
operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String
```

that allows `null + null` leveraging those coercion rules I mentioned above

Comment: I'm getting js vibes

Answer (score 4):

```
val x = null + null
```

Try to rephrase this as below and you will find you answer:

```
val x = null.plus(null)
```

The below is what IntelliJ shows as the signature of the `plus` method:

```
public operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String
```

So the first `null` is treated as `String?` type and then when you try to plus anything else, the above `plus` method is the only match you have. Printing out `x` will result in `nullnull`